Find intersection from a 3D polyline to a surface based on a defined angle
I have a raster surface representing the ground and a 3D polyline at a set height that represents the top of a dam wall.  I would like to project from the polyline down at say 25% below horizontal to create another polyline where it intersects the raster surface.
Is there a tool in QGIS that can generate this line.  Ideally the tool can identify when the polyline is below the raster surface also and skip these sections (ie no wall is required in this section.  It would be good to get a point every 10m or so along the original 3D polyline.
The reason I need this is to understand the extent of impacts from the wall downstream.
